# trying to deal with api response

Tags: api, response

This is my API response :

```
{"movie_results":[],"person_results":[],"tv_results":[],"tv_episode_results":[{"air_date":"1996-01-09","episode_number":1,"id":953004,"name":"Brains and Eggs","overview":"Solomon discovers that human bodies can produce feelings, and he's feeling attracted to a college professor with whom he shares an office.","production_code":"101","season_number":1,"show_id":155,"still_path":null,"vote_average":9.0,"vote_count":2}],"tv_season_results":[]}
```

when I use this code

```
$json = json_decode($response);

$array = get_object_vars($json);

if(empty($array['tv_episode_results'])){
    
  $db->query("INSERT INTO episodes (season_id,movie_id,episode_number,episode_name,episode_description,episode_thumbnail,episode_source,is_embed,actor_id,ratings,season_sub_id)

VALUES ('".$season_id."','".$video_id."','".$episode_number."','".$epName."','Discription Coming Soon.','814512c0eb40e98a0f15cf493f8c6096maxresdefault-1.jpg','".$source."','0','','','".$season_subnumber."')");

}
```

The episode_thumbnail in the database should have the 814512c0eb40e98a0f15cf493f8c6096maxresdefault-1.jpg
as default if the still path is null (from the response) but it doesn't seem to work. The rest of the code works fine.

Comment: to add default value instead of null, you should check in code otherwise you should use
IFNULL(episodeThumbnail,DEFAULT(episode_thumbnail)) this will set default value if the value is null

Comment: where would I add that please.